# Why do new lines keep appearing every time I append using "[,\n]" delimiter?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I'm new to java programming, and I currently build a program that updates an information from a user through file handling.

For instance, I have this initially saved in the notepad.

```
Milo,10,India
Jacob,15,California
Shan,7,France
```

I want to change the country. So I initialized a scanner to read every line in the file, with the delimiter ("[,\n]"). I was able to change it, but every time I do any changes, new lines appear every after each lines.

The output every time I append is like this: The new lines are appearing randomly, and I don't know why.

```
Milo,10,Italy
Jacob,15,California



Shan,7,France
```

Here is my code:

```
private static Scanner x;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("rewrite.txt");
        String nameString = "Milo";
        String newcountry = "Italy";
        
        String tempFile = "temp.txt";
        File oldFile = new File("rewrite.txt");
        File newFile = new File(tempFile);
        String name = ""; 
        String age = "";
        String country = "";
        
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            x = new Scanner(new File("rewrite.txt"));
            x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
            
            while(x.hasNext()) {
                name = x.next();
                age = x.next();
                country = x.next();
                
                if (name.equals(nameString)) {
                    
                    pw.println(name + "," + age + "," + newcountry);
                    System.out.println(name + "," + age + "," + newcountry);
                
                } else {
                    pw.println(name + "," + age + "," + country);
                    System.out.println(name + "," + age + "," + country);
                }
            }
            x.close();
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            oldFile.delete();
            File dump = new File("rewrite.txt");
            newFile.renameTo(dump);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

Comment: This is not the real code. This code does not produce this output. You are comparing `"Jacob"` to `""` over and over again: it is never true, so you are never doing the country replacement shown here. NB As a point of style, you have constructed `new File("rewrite.txt")` three times. You could have used one. Also `flush()` before `close()` is redundant.

Comment: I had some Strange experiences with `Scanner#useDelimiter`. I would suggest, you use `Scanner#nextLine` and split each line by `,` to get the fields

Comment: Oh, the 'number' is a typo, it should've been 'age' I'm sorry.

Comment: It's far from the only one. Why would you compare `age` to `nameString`? It doesn't make sense. Please copy and paste the real code. Your sample output shows that you have changed the country for Milo, but this code can never do that.

Comment: I've edited the code in my post now. I am sorry I had several changes after I posted my question.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer How can I change it to nextLine?

Comment: So you have four blank lines after 'California'? Do you have any after 'France'?

Comment: Remove `\n` from the delimiter and call `nextLine()` at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: @user207421 There's three more blank lines after France.

Comment: So that means that somehow `country` contains several newlines.

Comment: @user207421 do you mean at the bottom line after `while(x.hasNext()) {` or at the bottom of the end of the whole while loop?

Comment: Eh? There is only one `while` loop in the code you posted, and it only has one bottom. Don't ask meaningless questions.

Comment: @user207421 I'm so beginner in Java that's why I can't understand easily. Anyways, I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the whole line, split on the comma. Then assign the values to the variables and write to new file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File input = new File("C:\\temp\\input.txt");
    String nameString = "Milo";
    String newcountry = "Italy";

    File output = new File("c:\\temp\\temp.txt");
    String name = "";
    String age = "";
    String country = "";
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        Scanner x = new Scanner(input);
        while (x.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = x.nextLine();
            String[] split = line.split(",");
            name = split[0];
            age = split[1];
            country = split[2];
            if (name.equals(nameString)) {
                pw.println(name + "," + age + "," + newcountry);
                System.out.println(name + "," + age + "," + newcountry);
            } else {
                pw.println(name + "," + age + "," + country);
                System.out.println(name + "," + age + "," + country);
            }
        }
        x.close();
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Milo,10,Italy
Jacob,15,California
Shan,7,France
```

without any empty lines.

With some debugging, I found the issue, that you are experiencing. You only consume part of the new line delimiter:

> Text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings than files created on Unix/Linux. DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n")

When updating the delimiter to also consume `\r`, it works just as well

```
x.useDelimiter(",|\r\n");
```

This tell the scanner to use `,` or `\r\n` as delimiter which consumes the the windows new line characters

Comment: Well yeah but it can also be done with the `Scanner`, a bit more cleanly.

Comment: It uses the scanner?

Comment: Thank you for this @XtremeBaumer, I will study your code because it really worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user207421 I used scanner, but I don't know my mistake :<

Comment: `new FileWriter(output, true)` you append to the end of file instead of writing anew. replace `true` with `false`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Is it possible to just rewrite it within the same file?

Comment: In theory yes, in practice, its not really feasible. You would first need to read the whole file, then close the scanner. Afterwards create the `FileWriter` and write the content to it. It is easier to just do as you already do, with replacing the input file